# How do I fix building errors with Angular Material Components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cli

Am I missing something in the configuration?

#### ng Version command

```
Versions
Angular CLI: 1.7.0
Node: 8.1.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

@angular/animations: 5.2.9
@angular/cdk: 5.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.7.0
@angular/material: 5.2.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.1
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.0
@schematics/angular: 0.3.1
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.1
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack-bundle-analyzer: 2.11.1
webpack: 3.11.0
```

#### Repro steps

Step 1 Create new project ng new any-name
Step 2  By following steps on https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started
i.e

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

Step 3

#### Material.module.ts

```
import {MatButtonModule,
        MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
 @NgModule({
   imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule],
 })
 export class MaterialModule { }
```

#### app.component.html

```
<div>
  <input type="button" mat-button placeholder="Holla!">

  <button mat-raised-button >Click me!</button>
  <mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

#### App.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MaterialModule} from '../shared/material.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### styles.css

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

#### Observed behavior

compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

   Click me!
   [ERROR ->]Check me!

   "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@4:2
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
        at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24668)
        at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34621)
        at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34596)
        at eval (compiler.js:34497)
        at Set.forEach ()
        at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34497)
        at eval (compiler.js:34367)
        at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
    syntaxError @ compiler.js:485
    TemplateParser.parse @ compiler.js:24668
    JitCompiler._parseTemplate @ compiler.js:34621
    JitCompiler._compileTemplate @ compiler.js:34596
    (anonymous) @ compiler.js:34497
    JitCompiler._compileComponents @ compiler.js:34497
    (anonymous) @ compiler.js:34367
    then @ compiler.js:474
    JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:34366
    JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:34260
    CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:239
    PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5567
    (anonymous) @ main.ts:11
    ./src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:59
    __webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
    0 @ main.bundle.js:75
    __webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
    webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1

#### Desired behavior

What would like to see implemented?
It should load the angular material components.

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "mat-learn",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

#### Main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import 'hammerjs';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Show us `material.module`

Comment: i think you not import  @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css in style.css add this into style.css and check

Comment: Please check now I missed to add styles.css file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the example given here, you also need to export the material modules from your shared `material` module

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules

```
import {MatButtonModule,
        MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
 @NgModule({
   imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule],
   exports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule]
 })
 export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks David for quick reply. I have already imported the  required components in material.module.ts

Comment: I read your post too fast, sorry. You need to export them from that module too

Comment: yes, I have imported material module in appModule. or you want me to import the material components in my component?

Comment: No, in your material module you need to specify the `export` property like in the example above. Basically you import AND export the material modules from your shared componnet

Answer (score 14):

**@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";**
add this in style.css

Comment: can i check your style.css

Comment: i change my answer please check it

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Issue was because of missing export

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something for a while. But I had just one typo in an import making the whole "Module import" clause fail.

My import was:

```
import { PopoverModule } from '_components/material/popover';
```

Instead of:

```
import { PopoverModule } from './_components/material/popover';
```

And it triggered 15+ unrelated errors about material ui components.