# Each checkbox is showing up twice

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-flex-layout

I am trying mat-checkbox in Angular. Basically trying to design payment method UI. So, I used mat-checkbox to select one payment method. But each box is showing up double. Here I am adding my code:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
          <p>Select Payment Method</p>
          <mat-checkbox>Cash On Delivery</mat-checkbox>
          <mat-checkbox>Online Payment</mat-checkbox>
          <mat-checkbox>Wallet</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
```

Also I am adding an Image of my UI:

[image]

Comment: Some CSS it missing. How did you add material in your project. Did you run `ng add @angular/material` ?

Comment: @StPaulis I added material by "npm install --save @angular/material".

But is it necessary to add css till I don't want to change any style?

Comment: I suggest you to follow the official docs: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: @StPaulis Yes, Problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like some `material` styling is missing.

Check the installation guide from the official docs: [Angular Material | Getting Started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

> ng add @angular/material

```
The ng add command will install Angular Material, the Component Dev Kit (CDK), Angular Animations and ask you the following questions to determine which features to include:

    Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme:

    You can choose from prebuilt material design themes or set up an extensible custom theme.

    Set up global Angular Material typography styles:

    Whether to apply the global typography styles to your application.

    Set up browser animations for Angular Material:

    Importing the BrowserAnimationsModule into your application enables Angular's animation system. Declining this will disable most of Angular Material's animations.

The ng add command will additionally perform the following configurations:

    Add project dependencies to package.json
    Add the Roboto font to your index.html
    Add the Material Design icon font to your index.html
    Add a few global CSS styles to:
        Remove margins from body
        Set height: 100% on html and body
        Set Roboto as the default application font
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, when i tried to add angular material in an existing project and the style.css file didn't update properly.

Here what i did:

- Go to file style.css of the project.

  Add: @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
  //Use the prebuilt theme name you choose.

You can found more info here: [How do I fix building errors with Angular Material Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552161/how-do-i-fix-building-errors-with-angular-material-components)

Hope that's help.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this with CSS we can use the below code:

```css
.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-checkmark{
   opacity: 0 !important;
}
```